# Sorting a hash table and printing key and value at the same time

Tags: python, sorting, hashtable

I have written a program in python, where I have used a hash table to read data from a file and then add data in the last column of the file corresponding to the values in the 2nd column of the file. for example, for all entries in column 2 with same values, the corresponding last column values will be added.

Now I have implemented the above successfully.  Now I want to sort the table in descending order according to last column values and print these values and the corresponding 2nd column (key) values. i am not able to figure out on how to do this. Can anyone please help ?

pmt txt file is of the form

```
0.418705 2 3 1985 20 0
0.420657 4 5 119 3849 5 
0.430000 2 3 1985 20 500
```

and so on...

So, for example, for number 2 in column 2, i have added all data of last column corresponding to all numbers '2' in the 2nd column. So, this process will continue for the next set of numbers lie 4, 5 ,etc in column 2.

I'm using python 3

```
import math

source_ip = {}
f = open("pmt.txt","r",1)
lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    s_ip = line.split()[1]
    bit_rate = int(line.split()[-1]) + 40
    if s_ip in source_ip.keys():
       source_ip[s_ip] = source_ip[s_ip] + bit_rate
       print (source_ip[s_ip])
    else:
       source_ip[s_ip] = bit_rate

f.close()

for k in source_ip.keys():
    print(str(k)+": "+str(source_ip[k]))
    print ("-----------")
```

Comment: Please provide a brief example of the contents of `pmt.txt`. There is likely a much better way to do this than what you've implemented, but there's only so much we can do without seeing example input. Also please indicate whether you are using Python 2 or 3.

Comment: pmt txt file is of the form

0.418705 2 3 1985 20 0
0.420657 4 5 119 3849 5 
0.430000 2 3 1985 20 500
and so on...

So, for example, for number 2 in column 2, i have added all data of last column corresponding to all numbers '2' in the 2nd column. So, this process will continue for the next set of numbers lie 4, 5 ,etc in column 2.

I'm using python 3

Comment: Will you please edit that into your question, properly formatted? (4 leading spaces each line for monospace and gray background.)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use the `sorted` function with a `key` parameter that gets the value from the key/value tuple:

```
sorted_items = sorted(source_ip.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

You could also use `itemgetter` from the `operator` module, rather than a lambda function:

```
import operator
sorted_items = sorted(source_ip.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: I think it's supposed to be sorted by key (`x[0]`).

Comment: It needs to be sorted based on the values of the last column obtained after addition corresponding to column 2 entry, i.e need to sort source_ip[s_ip] in descending order, and print the sorted values and the corresponding keys.

Comment: @user3547134: If you want descending order rather than ascending, add a `reverse=True` argument to `sorted`, in addition to the `key` function.

Comment: Can anyone please tell how to write these values into a file instead of the terminal, because the on the terminal, I'm not able to see all values, as there is a lot of stuff in the txt file

Comment: @user3547134: Try using the `file` keyword-only argument to `print`.

Comment: Now for the sorted columns, for the 1st 3 entries, I need to take the corresponding next column value (value) and divide it by the total values in that column (total of all values). I tried using remove command, so that removing each max entry and then again finding max value of whole thing (to get 2nd max value) and then 3 rd max value. But remove does'nt work with the hash tables

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.4/bin/python

import collections

source_ip = collections.defaultdict(int)
with open("pmt.txt","r",1) as file_:
    for line in file_:
        fields = line.split()
        s_ip = fields[1]
        bit_rate = int(fields[-1]) + 40
        source_ip[s_ip] += bit_rate
        print (source_ip[s_ip])

for key, value in sorted(source_ip.items()):
    print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))
    print ("-----------")
```

Comment: But what about the sorting ??

Comment: I've added sorting and eliminated the big inhale.

Comment: Now for the sorted columns, for the 1st 3 entries, I need to take the corresponding next column value (value) and divide it by the total values in that column (total of all values). I tried using remove command, so that removing each max entry and then again finding max value of whole thing (to get 2nd max value) and then 3 rd max value. But remove does'nt work with the hash tables